# compose with vertx for sequential code

Tags: vert.x

I have two operations step_1() and step_2() and want to execute step_2() AFTER step_1().

With normal java this would be:

```
step_1();
step_2();
```

With vertx I have to use vertx-compose(). Am I right?

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/FuvlPLpoGOA, I dont need Futures for sequential code.

> "If you want to do each request sequencially you dont need futures."

So how can I do that without using futures?

I dont know, if this matters: My Vertx from which this code is executed is a "Worker"-Verticle.

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws IOException {

Future<Void> step_1 = Future.future();
    step_1.compose(res -> {
        // If the future succeeded
        Future<Void> step_2 = step_1();

        step_2.compose(res2 -> {
            step_2();

        }, Future.future().setHandler(handler -> {
            // If the future failed
        }));

        //I dont need that
    }, Future.future().setHandler(handler -> {
        // If the future failed
    }));

}

public void step_1(){
..
}

public void step_2(){
..
}
```

Is this the right and shortest (!) way?

Comment: Clarity over the question would be really helpful here, because some how you have defined `step_1()` as returning `void` but you are showing as if you are getting `Future` from it, you intentions are clear that you want `step1` execution and then execute `step2`, are they inherently `blocking` and is that the reason you want to have `worker` `verticle`. Please clarify so that we can all you better.

Comment: I am getting a Future<Void>. However, the only thing I need, is to make "step1" and then "step2". I guess, a "worker verticle" does not make the whole code within the start-method blocking, or? If so, then I do not need a Future<Void>.

Comment: Thanks, and indeed you are correct `Worker` verticle does no magic of that sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If you want to do each request sequencially you dont need futures."

No, it's not. In asynchronous frameworks like Vert.x, input/output operations are non-blocking. It means, that if you call few asynchronous operations, they'll start working simultaneously. And if you want to do few requests sequentially, then you should use futures or callbacks to execute new request only after previous one finished successfully.

Check this [code](https://github.com/sczyh30/vertx-blueprint-todo-backend/blob/919541896b544fcccd4963e46e26274e0aff8997/src/main/java/io/vertx/blueprint/todolist/service/RedisTodoService.java#L87) with futures, [newer version](https://github.com/sczyh30/vertx-blueprint-todo-backend/blob/4e06d6a11b4e61aac9bc52f3ca30bf48962afb76/src/main/java/io/vertx/blueprint/todolist/service/RedisTodoService.java#L70) with RxJava 2 and [article](http://www.sczyh30.com/vertx-blueprint-todo-backend/) about project.

```
@Override
public Future<Optional<Todo>> getCertain(String todoID) {
    Future<Optional<Todo>> result = Future.future();
    redis.hget(Constants.REDIS_TODO_KEY, todoID, res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            result.complete(Optional.ofNullable(
                res.result() == null ? null : new Todo(res.result())));
        } else
            result.fail(res.cause());
    });
    return result;
}

@Override
public Future<Todo> update(String todoId, Todo newTodo) {
    return this.getCertain(todoId).compose(old -> {
        if (old.isPresent()) {
            Todo fnTodo = old.get().merge(newTodo);
            return this.insert(fnTodo)
                .map(r -> r ? fnTodo : null);
        } else {
            return Future.succeededFuture();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Below is an example of chaining of `Future`, I have made the example very trivial nonetheless it showcases the concept.

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class Chaining {
    private Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    @Test
    public void futures_chaining(TestContext context) throws Exception {
        Async async = context.async();

        firstOperation()
                .compose((outcome) -> {
                    System.out.println(outcome);

                    return secondOperation();
                })
                .compose(outcome -> {
                    System.out.println(outcome);

                    /*
                      For stopping unit test we are returning this future                                                                                                                                                              
                      for production use-case this would be Future.succeededFuture 
                      or Future.failedFuture depending on your method outcomes
                     */
                    return Future.future(handle -> async.complete());
                });
    }

    private Future<String> firstOperation() {
        Future<String> future = Future.future();

        vertx.setTimer(1000, delay -> future.complete("First Operation Complete"));

        return future;
    }

    private Future<String> secondOperation() {
        Future<String> future = Future.future();

        vertx.setTimer(1000, delay -> future.complete("Second Operation Complete"));

        return future;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RxJava exists specifically to compose async events: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java/

Assuming both step_1() and step_1() aren't designed to return results (i.e. they effectively return *void*) then you could change them to return Observable or Single and chain them together similar to this:

```
step_1().doOnSuccess(this::step_2()).subscribe(/* control resumes here */);
```

RxJava (or rather, reactive programming in general) takes a little bit to wrap your head around it, but I would strongly recommend using it if you're planning to chain together async operations.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `step_2` as argument to `step_1`

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> fut) throws IOException {
    step_1(step_2);
}

private void step_1(Runnable function){
    someAsynccall("some-arg", response -> {
        function.run();
    }).end();
}

private void step_2(){
    // do something
}
```